# Tarfile extracting path cannot include special characters

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, utf-8, tarfile

I want to extract tarfile to it's own path but if the file's path contains any special characters(like ö).

If I don't give extracting path, it extracts tarfile to my project directory.

Here is my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import tarfile, os

filepath = u"C:\\Users\\Ayse\\Desktop\\somefolderö\\tarfile.tar.gz"
dirname = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(filepath))
dirname = dirname.encode('utf-8')

tar = tarfile.open(filepath, "r:gz")
tar.extractall(path=dirname) #error occurs on this line
tar.close()
```

I get this error on **tar.extractall(path=dirname)** line:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xf6 in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I tried to encode the path variable like this:

```
filepath = filepath.encode('utf-8')
```

After encoding, code works without error. However, tarfile will be extracted to **somefolderÃ¶** folder. I want to extract it to **somefolderö**.

Long story short, **ö** becomes **Ã¶**.

I'm using python 2.7 on Windows 8.1.

Comment: That looks a lot like you have *latin-1* decoded the string. When you print dirname  what does it look like?

Comment: I printed it, looks correct: "C:\Users\Ayse\Desktop\somefolderö"

Comment: Somewhere it is getting encoded to latin-1, what is your default encoding?